# Does there always exist a(n uniform) polynomial that makes a positive definite symmetric matrix with polynomial entries into a sum of squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, sums-of-squares, positivity

Suppose that I have a square and positive definite for every evaluation $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ symmetric matrix $M(x)\in(\mathbb{R}[x])^{s\times s}.$

1. Does there always exist a polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $p(x)M(x)$ is a sum of squares?
2. Can we chose this polynomial uniformly for every matrix up to some exponent, i.e., does there exist $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that for every such matrix $M(x)$ there exist $k$ such that $p(x)^kM(x)$ is a sum of squares matrix?

I know that the there are several Positivstellensätze that can achieve these things when $s=1$ (which is the just polynomial case) but I am not sure if this is doable for matrix polynomials.